# About basis of vector space of polynomial degree less than n

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $r \in \mathbb{R}$ be an arbitrary real number. Show that $\beta=\left\{1, x-r,(x-r)^{2},(x-r)^{3}, \ldots,(x-r)^{n}\right\}$ is a basis of $P_{n}(\mathbb{R})$.

I know that if I can show this vectors are linearly independent then this constitute basis of $P_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ since dimension is $n+1$ for this space. So only need to show this are linearly independent.

I set linear combination to be 0. Then try to differntiate linear combination to get value of coeeficient .But I am not getting my result.

Answer (score 1):

If $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} a_i(x-r)^{i}=0$ for all $x$ then $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} a_ix^{i}=0$ for all $x$ and when  a polynomial vanishes all its coefficients also vanish.

Comment: How do you conclude directly $\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_{i} x^{i}=0$ ?

Comment: @mathsstudent If the equation holds for all real numbers $x$ then we can legitimately replace $x$ by $x+r$ because $x+r$ is also  a real number.

Comment: sure thanks sir

Answer (score 1):

For any $p \in P_n(\Bbb{R})$ by induction we get
$$p(t) = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{p^{(k)}(r)}{k!}(x-r)^k$$
so the set $\beta$ spans $P_n(\Bbb{R})$. Since $|\beta| = n+1$, we conclude that it is a basis.